# Highcharts - Long xlabel content leads to huge white space over chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, offset, label

Please take a look at [this fiddle (long labels)](http://jsfiddle.net/e2m0o138/8/). The xaxis has `opposite:true`.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3'],
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    alternateGridColor: 'gray',
    opposite: true,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'very very very very very very very very very very very veryvery very very very very very very veryvery very very very very veryvery very very very very veryvery very very very very veryvery very very very very very very long.';
        },
        style: {
            'background-color': 'red'
        },
        useHTML: true
    }
}
```

Why does Highcharts position the large labels so vertically overlapping? Any ideas on how to make the labels appear a little higher?

[image: To describe what I mean, here comes a screenshot]

### EDIT:

Restructured my question and added another fiddle + screenshot. Thanks for answers. :)

Comment: Downvoting is no solution, nor an explanaition of the behavior described above...

Comment: What is even stranger: When making the y offset even bigger for the large label, the white space persists: http://jsfiddle.net/e2m0o138/7/

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by setting y parameter which you have. So when your labels are short, there are position (-50px as you defined) so gap is printed.

Comment: I agree, but the problem is: No matter how much y offset is set, the white space persists. It is always added. There is no chance of having a long label with no white space over it. I consider that a bug.

Comment: updated my questions to make the problem more clear. :)

Comment: So generally, you asked why highcharst not set enough space for long labels, where there are at the top? Right? I reported it as possibly bug [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3682)